# How to cast Observable to FirebaseObjectObservable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

**Code**:

(The casting doesn't work in both of the methods)

```
1. this.af.database.object('/users/'+key)
          .do((something:any)=>console.log(something)) as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
2. ..switchMap(()=>this.af.database.object('/users/'+key)) as FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the problem?
2. Can I replace the 'any' with 'User' type everywhere without losing any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay solved it:

```
1. <FirebaseObjectObservable<any>>this.af.database.object('/users/'+key)
          .do((something:any)=>console.log(something));
2. <FirebaseObjectObservable<any>>..switchMap(()=>this.af.database.object('/users/'+key));
```

And for replacing the `any`, I added in my user class a `$key` property so now I can do:

```
1. <FirebaseObjectObservable<User>>this.af.database.object('/users/'+key)
          .do((something:any)=>console.log(something));
2. <FirebaseObjectObservable<User>>..switchMap(()=>this.af.database.object('/users/'+key));
```